# Function returns 0 with any input

Tags: c++

I some C++ code (find.cpp) that is supposed to take two numbers at the end of a character sequence and print them as an integer.

find.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "find_num.h"

int main() {
    char test[6] = { 't', 'e', 's', 't', '4', '2' };

    std::cout << find_num(test) << std::endl;
}
```

find_num.h:

```
#include <sstream>

int find_num(char char_in[]) {
    char char_out[2];
    int out;

    for (int i = 0, end = true; end!=false; i++) {
        if (char_in[i] == 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                char_out[j] = char_in[i - 2 + j];
            }
            std::stringstream(char_out) >> out;
            end = false;
        }
    }

    return out;
}
```

For some reason, when I compile and run find.cpp, it always prints 0, though I would expect it to print 42. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: You don't have a *script* and you don't *run* a `.cpp` file.

Comment: It works on my compiler(Dev c++) and prints 42. It may be relevant with your compiler.

Comment: @Kemal It has nothing to do with his compiler.

Comment: @LogicStuff Sorry, I have some _code_ and I _compiled and ran_ find.cpp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This string:

```
   char test[6] = { 't', 'e', 's', 't', '4', '2' };
```

will not be null-terminated. You want:

```
   char test[7] = { 't', 'e', 's', 't', '4', '2', 0 };
```

or better:

```
   char test[] = "test42";
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, when I had the function in the same script, it worked without test having the 7th element. Why?

Comment: Undefined behaviour - anything could happen, including the program appearing to "work".